# Finding sum of number nearest to specific number

Tags: r

I have following vector of numbers in r

```
bay_no <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
bay_cont <- c(45,25,25,0,19,61,2,134,5,27,0,54,102,97,5,6,65,47,85,0)
count <- 3
bay_to_serve <- sum(bay_cont)/count
```

In above `bay_cont` vector I want to find sum which will be close to `bay_to_serve` in above case `bay_to_serve = 268`

Now, from `(45 till 2) sum is 177 and (45 till 134) sum is 311`,so `311 is closest to 268` then it should return the index of `i.e 8 from bay_no`

We will get one vector from `bay_no = 1-8`

Again starting from `bay_cont from 5 till the sum close to 268`

Desired output is

`bay_no 1-8,9-14 and then remaining bay_nos`

How can we do it in r?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution uses a dirty for loop but yields the required indizes...
Hope that fits to you?

```
  bay_no <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
    bay_cont <- c(45,25,25,0,19,61,2,134,5,27,0,54,102,97,5,6,65,47,85,0)
    count <- 3
    bay_to_serve <- sum(bay_cont)/count


    temp_sum=0
    for (i in 1:(length(bay_cont)-1)) {
      temp_sum=temp_sum+bay_cont[i]
      if ( abs(bay_to_serve-temp_sum)<abs(bay_to_serve-(temp_sum +bay_cont[i+1]))) {
        print(i)
        temp_sum=0
      }

    }
```

Comment: how can i store values of output in 3 different vectors ? A = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) B=(9,10,11,12,13,14) C =(15,16,17,18,19,20)

Comment: @Neil: 1 .initialize a list outside the for-loop. L=list() 2. initialize a variable j=1 outside the for-loop 3. inside the if-statement use: L=list(L,j:i) & set set j=i

Comment: its giving me only 2 elements of vectors inside the list. `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` and `8,9,10,11,12,13,14` I want `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 9,10,11,12,13,14 and 15,16,17,18,19,20`

Comment: @Nail: Just add another L=list(L,j+1:length(bay_no) at the end of the code

Answer (score 2):

Dunno if there is a smart way to do but I'd think of nested loops.
Your inner loop may look like this (Please note that I have no access to R right now, so I can't test it.):

```
old_sum = bay_count[1]
for(i in 2:length(by_cont)) {
  new_sum <- sum (bay_count[1:i])
  if (abs(bay_to_serve - new_sum) < abs(bay_to_serve - old_sum)) {
    output <- paste("bay_no", paste(1,i, sep="-"), sep=" ") break
  }else{
    old_sum <- new_sum
  }
}
```

This way, whenever the sum of the first X entries is smaller than the previous sum, it will break the loop and create an output string. Just add another loop around the first loop and one or to more if statements to run from j:length(by_cont), whereby j is first set to 1 and will be set to i+1 within the inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
res <- NULL
i = 1
while(i < length(bay_cont)){
 tmp <-  which.min(abs(cumsum(bay_cont[i:length(bay_cont)]) - bay_to_serve))
 res <- append(res,tmp)
 i = tmp + i
}
cumsum(res)
[1]  8 14 19
```

If you want to break ties specifically you can use `rank` together with `which.min` like follows:

```
which.min(rank(abs(cumsum(bay_cont[i:length(bay_cont)]) - bay_to_serve), ties.method = "last"))
```

Then I would create a matrix instead of pasting it together:

```
cbind(c(1, cumsum(res)[-length(cumsum(res))]+1), cumsum(res))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    8
[2,]    9   14
[3,]   15   19
```

Of course you can paste it together as well:

```
apply(cbind(c(1, cumsum(res)[-length(cumsum(res))]+1), cumsum(res)), 1, paste, collapse="-")
[1] "1-8"   "9-14"  "15-19"
```

Comment: Nice. Surprisingly compact.

Answer (score 0):

I probably misunderstand the question, but it seems more easy to do this:

```
bay_no[ which.min(abs(cumsum(bay_cont) - bay_to_serve)) ]
```

To start at 5, omit elements 1:4 and add 4 to the which.min index

```
bay_no[ which.min(abs(cumsum(bay_cont[-(1:4)]) - bay_to_serve))+4 ]
```

Comment: Aha and what is the difference to my answer? In addition you get not the wanted expected output with your code...

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed that you answered the same. I stopped reading when I saw the while loop... Well, at least we independently came up with basically the same code ;-)